# how to get data to html <ul> <li> </li> </ul> list from mysql database with php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a video player and want to populate video on it from mysql database, here is my code.

```
<ul id="playlist1" style="display:none;">
    <li data-thumb-source="assets/img/ddd.jpg" data-video-source="assets/video/ddd.mp4" data-poster-source="assets/img/ddd.jpg" data-downloadable="yes">
        <div data-video-short-description="">
            <div>
                <p class="minimalDarkThumbnailTitle">ddd</p>
                <p class="minimalDarkThumbnailDesc">dddd.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-video-long-description="">
            <div>
                <p class="minimalDarkVideoTitleDesc">dddd</p>
                <p class="minimalDarkVideoMainDesc">ddd</p>
                <p>For more information about this please follow <a href="#" target="_blank">this link</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My MySQL database has the following columns

- id
- data-thumb-source
- data-video-source
- data-poster-source
- minimalDarkThumbnailTitle
- minimalDarkThumbnailDesc

My PHP code to get the data from the database:

```
<?php
    $result= mysql_query("select * from video order by id  DESC" ) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array ($result) ){
    $id=$row['id'];
?>
```

However, my video player is blank because it has nothing to play.

**Edit:** I used this code to display my value

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $li  = '<li> data-thumb-source="' .$row['data-thumb-source']. '"';
        $li .= ' class="playlistItem" data-type="local"';
        $li .= ' data-video-source="' .$row['data-video-source']. '"';
        $li .= ' minimalDarkThumbnailTitle="' .$row['minimalDarkThumbnailTitle']. '"';
        $li .= ' minimalDarkThumbnailDesc="' .$row['minimalDarkThumbnailDesc']. '"';
        echo $li;
    }
    $db = null;
?>
</ul>
```

This did not make a difference though.

Comment: first of all -  how you try to display your values from the $id array?

Comment: @metamorph_online i ve updated my question to ur request

Comment: you missed a closing bracket after the li

Comment: still not working @user3807877

Answer (score 0):

You closed your opening `li` tag before defining the attributes.

```
<ul>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`";
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $li  = '<li data-thumb-source="' .$row['data-thumb-source']. '"';
    $li .= ' class="playlistItem" data-type="local"';
    $li .= ' data-video-source="' .$row['data-video-source']. '"';
    $li .= ' minimalDarkThumbnailTitle="' .$row['minimalDarkThumbnailTitle']. '"';
    $li .= ' minimalDarkThumbnailDesc="' .$row['minimalDarkThumbnailDesc']. '"';
    echo $li . '>descriptions</li>';
}
$db = null;
?>
</ul>
```