# How to save ul li variables to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i have such an example... From here (http://jsfiddle.net/tpgun6Lz/5/) i have dropdown menu(with images) using ul li (in my example there will be few different menu).
Here is a code - i can add the id to `<ul>`(but as you will see jquery using class not using id), and data-value to `<li>` for the purpose of solve problem:

```
<ul class="prod-gram" id="menu">
    <li class="init" data-value="1"><img src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/hej.png" /> Country 1</li>
    <li data-value="2"><img src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/hej.png" /> Country 1</li>
    <li data-value="3"><img src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/hej.png" /> Country 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="prod-gram" id="menu2">
    <li class="init" data-value="1"><img src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/hej.png" /> Country 1</li>
    <li data-value="2"><img src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/hej.png" /> Country 1</li>
    <li data-value="3"><img src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/hej.png" /> Country 2</li>
</ul>
```

and javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", "ul.prod-gram .init", function() {
            $(this).parent().find('li:not(.init)').toggle();
        });
        var allOptions = $("ul.prod-gram").children('li:not(.init)');
        $("ul.prod-gram").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
            allOptions.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).parent().children('.init').html($(this).html()); // this line colide with ajax
            $(this).parent().find('li:not(.init)').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to save value ul(id), and value li (data-value) in `PHP` using `jQuery` and ajax. I prepare some code but I don't know how to setup them(I'm not sure about variables setup and ajax):

```
<script>
    $('#menu').click(function(){
        var liValue = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-value');
        var ulId = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'humourvalue.php',
            data:{ul: ulId, li: liValue},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#menu").html(data); // i tried to change datatype but then i cant send them to php
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and file humourvalue.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/config.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        if ($userID === null) {
            $userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        }

        $userID = intval($userID);
        $ulId = $db->$_POST['ul'])));
        $liValue = $db->$_POST['li'])));
        $result = $db->query("UPDATE `users` SELECT `opts`='".($ulId)."' WHERE id=".($userID));
    }

?>
```

I'm not sure if this topic will be helpful to get data from database: [how to get data to html <ul> <li> </li> </ul> list from mysql database with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270706/how-to-get-data-to-html-ul-li-li-ul-list-from-mysql-database-with-php)

I need to focus first how to save variables in database. Please help me with this, course it makes me crazy.

------------------UPDATE------------
Now i undertand - the javascript code colide with ajax call, couse we have

`$(this).parent().children('.init').html($(this).html());`

in javascript and in ajax we have

```
success: function(data) {
         $("#menu").html(data);
```

Can anyone have some idea how to fix it?

Comment: _I need to focus first how to save variables in database._ That you do! And for that there is a MySQL User Manual and thousands of tutorial out there on the web that will help you seperate your UDPATES from your SELECTS. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: Your `UPDATE` is incorrect, and open to SQL injections. Unclear though if the JS makes it that far or the issue is with JS.

Comment: Hi, you need to get value of `li` which is clicked ? or all lis ?

Comment: Swati, if this is the question - yes, i need get value of li which is clicked, all of lis

Answer (score -1):

here we go, i found one of the solution for this question:

html file:

```
<ul class="prod-gram" id="menu">
    <li class="init" data-value="value 1"><img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/ph.png' /> Country 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 1"><img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/ph.png' /> Country 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/cr.png' /> Country 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/nc.png' /> Country 3</li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/se.png' /> Country 4</li>
  </ul>
```

it should be like this in javascript, especially this variable liValue:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "ul.prod-gram .init", function() {
    $(this).parent().find('li:not(.init)').toggle();
  });
  var allOptions = $("ul.prod-gram").children('li:not(.init)');
  $("ul.prod-gram").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().children('.init').html($(this).html());
    $(this).parent().find('li:not(.init)').toggle();
  });
});

$("#menu").click(function() {
  var liValue = $("ul.prod-gram").find(".selected").data("value");
  var ulId = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
  alert(liValue);
});
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23oumxaf/24/
Now i just have problem with sending data into database, i dont know what is wrong with this:

```
  $liValue = $db->$_POST['li'];
  $ulId = $db->$_POST['ul'];
  $result = $db->query("UPDATE `users` SET `li`='".$liValue."'  WHERE id=".($userID));
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is creating new variable `var info` with data in ajax call (without it like in previous verision the data is not loaded):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", "ul.prod-gram .init", function() {
            $(this).parent().find("li:not(.init)").toggle();
        });
        var allOptions = $("ul.prod-gram").children("li:not(.init)");
        $("ul.prod-gram").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
            allOptions.removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $(this).parent().children(".init").html($(this).html());
            $(this).parent().find("li:not(.init)").toggle();
        });
    });

$("#menu").click(function(){
    var liValue = $("ul.prod-gram").find(".selected").data("value");
    var ulId = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
    var info = {                                  // here is the modification
        "li":liValue,
        "ul":ulId
    };
    console.log(info);

    $.ajax({
        data: info,
        url: "humourvalue.php",
        type: "POST",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            console.log("finished");
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And humourvalue.php file:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

require_once 'includes/config.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    if ($userID === null) {
        $userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }

    $userID = intval($userID);
    $result = $db->query("UPDATE `users` SET `li`='".$_POST['li']."', `ul`='".$_POST['ul']."' WHERE id=".($userID));
    echo JSON_ENCODE($result);
}

?>
```

Now i have data in database.
I'm not sure if i don't need to set third variable which can be `init`.

Comment: solution is important to me, the question i can edit and remove